# Proving that $(\|T_{N}x\|)_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence for each fixed $x.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, solution-verification

Here is the question:

Let $A = [a_{ij}]_{i,j = 1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite matrix of real numbers and suppose that, for any $x \in \ell^2,$ the sequence $Ax$ belongs to $\ell^2.$ Prove that the operator $T,$ defined by $T(x) = Ax,$ is a bounded operator on $\ell^2.$

**Here is my trial: **

We will use the uniform bounded theorem Principle. Using that $T_{N}x = \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{ij}x_{j}$

I have proved that $T_N$ is bounded with $\|T_N \| \leq (\sum_{j=1}^{N} |a_{ij}|^2)^{1/2}.$.... am I correct?

Now I am stuck in proving that $(\|T_{N}x\|)_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence for each fixed $x.$ I need a condition on $x$ like it has finitely many nonzero terms or any other condition or here is what the given that for each x the sequence $Ax \in l^2$ comes into play?Could anyone help me in this, please?

Comment: Your formula for the norm of $T_N$ is incorrect (and an explicit formula is irrelevant). Your strategy to use uniform boundedness is a good one, but your formula is missing indices to be intelligible, at any rate you should think carefully about how you should want to cut off the indices to guaranteed that $\|T_Nx\|$ is bounded.

Comment: @s.harp  I have taken this proposition: "The series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{n}$ converges absolutely for every convergent sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ iff $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} |a_{n}|$ converges." will it be helpful here in our case?

Comment: @s.harp I do not understand the first line in your comment ... could you please explain it in details?

Comment: @s.harp I do not know how should I cut off indices to guarantee that $\|T_{N} x\|$ is bounded could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You are told that $\ Ax\in l^2\ $. Instead of $\ T_N\ $, consider the operators $\ S_{MN}\ $ defined by
$$
(S_{MN}x)_i=\cases{\sum_\limits{j=1}^N a_{ij}x_j& if $\ i\le M\ $\\
0 & if $\ i>M\ $,}
$$
and note that  $\ \left\|S_{MN}x\right\|_{l^2}\le \|Ax|_M\| _{l^2}\ $ for all $\ x\ $, where $\ x|_M\ $ is the sequence obtained from $\ x\ $ by replacing all its entries beyond the $\ M$-th to zero.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106615/discussion-on-answer-by-lonza-leggiera-proving-that-t-nx-n-in-mathbb).